# pass dynamic javascript variable to bean:message as argument struts

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts-1

I need to pass variable to struts bean:message.

```
 E.g
 var language = document.myForm.language.options[index].innerHTML;
 <bean:message key="current.lang" arg0="{{HERE I NEED TO PASS language}}"/>
```

Please suggest if there is a way for it ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. What you could to is post the form and then use [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) to pass the language parameter:

```
<bean:message key="current.lang" arg0="${param.language}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's old, but perhaps somebody needs this in legacy code:

Define a placeholder in message and the replace it in Javascript.

Message.properties:

```
current.lang=Current languega is :currentLanguage:
```

Javascript:

```
var language = document.myForm.language.options[index].innerHTML;
var text = '<bean:message key="current.lang"/>';
alert(text.replace(':currentLanguage:', language));
```